# How can I re-run java code from the java program?

Tags: java

I am trying to re-run my java code inside the java program, which is basically making CSV file of some data, 
I can't find some better solution. I tried to use the go-to: statement but does not work and stop the program

```
public class CSV { 
  String data1; 
  String data2; 

  restart: FileInputStream ar= new FileInputStream("filelocation");  
           FileWriter dr= new Filewriter("datafile.csv"); 
           dr.close(); 
          { 
              if (data=some number) { 
                  break restart;
              } 
              else { 
                  result=data1+data2; 
              } 
              ar.close(); 
           } 
  }
```

Comment: Can you update the code to something that compiles?

Comment: Re-run means automatically start from the beginning without stopping the main function which is read data from the sensor and save it CSV file

Comment: This code doesn't even compile, and the solution is trivial: just rearrange the loop.

Comment: **bold**@Thilo its just an example code

Comment: I'd say just put everything in a method, and then have the caller of that method call it again if necessary (there can be a loop in there, you can have a return value to pass out enough information to make that decision).

Comment: Don't "re-run" your program, "re-run" the method : `while(checkCondition(...){buildCsv(...);}`

Comment: @AxelH can you show me, more clearly? I am new in JAVA sorry

Comment: Not really, your sample don't compile so I can't really provide a working solution from this.

Comment: What a day, I haven't seen a `break label` used in ages and then it's a second time today. Please, do **NOT** use that construct. Labels are pure evil. And go-to, it is even worse. Just forget that those exist before you get used to those. There won't ever by need to use them anyway, there are always better solutions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why dont you use recursion. put the file writing code into one method.
Giving blueprint below please try to implement that way.

```
    public class CSV { 
      String data1; 
      String data2; 
      boolean runnung=false; 
      int globalvariable = 1;
      public void fileWrite(){  
               FileInputStream ar= new FileInputStream("filelocation");  
               FileWriter dr= new Filewriter("datafile"+globalvariable.csv"); 
               dr.close(); 
               //while (running) { 
                  if (data=some number) { 
                      fileWrite();
                  } else { 
                      result=data1+data2; 
                  } 
                  ar.close(); 
               //} 
           }
      }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This could produce a stack overflow and fails to properly close the file created.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel  as i have mentioned its a blue print of course you need to take care of file closing and opening operation. But one thing i am pretty much sure he can resolve this problem using recursion

Comment: It might be possible to solve this with recursion, but that doesn't mean it is a good idea. Nor does it address the issues that arise when the recursive call returns.

Comment: What could be the best solution for this then , according to you ?

Comment: Use a return value to determine the next action and call the method again based on that, or define an object that has state to track if the method should be called again, or something similar.

Comment: I think that condition is doing same , if condition will be true then only method will be called. And my intention to show him a way to achieve it by the way.

Comment: Don't use recursion as a looping construct. Use it when you *need* it.